# Exporting data to excel file using jquery along with css in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery

how to export data to excel with css themes using jquery?
Is there any jquery plugin to export data to excel with css

Comment: this will help you . [link] https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/phpexcel

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not support xls export directly. You have to couple the export functionality to an xls converter library. One ideal candidate is [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). If you really want to stick with jQuery, then Ajax is the way to go. You couple the action to a Codeigniter controller and inside the controller you convert the document to an xls file.

Here are some examples you can try: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples

Regarding your last question: you can not apply css style rules to an excel file. What you need instead is to create some style definition and apply to xls.

```
$styleArray = array(
    'font' => array(
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF')
));
$textAlign = array(
    'alignment' => array(
        'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER
));  

// Apply styles to cells
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A10')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A10')->applyFromArray($textAlign);
```